# Is Google Analytics blocked in China?

Tags: google, google-analytics

Our site has recored significantly drop in visitors from China from Google Analytics recently. Do you have the same observation?

Answer (score 4):

China pretty much [blocked Google wholesale](http://techcrunch.com/2012/11/09/china-blocks-virtually-all-of-googles-web-services-as-18th-party-congress-gets-underway/) during a Communist Party congress. There are [reports](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2013780/google-is-back-online-in-china-after-blocking.html) things are back to normal now.

I haven't seen a comprehensive list of what services were blocked(many stories only mention a few by name, so it's unclear if it was really everything or what), but if what you see started around the 8th, then that's probably what happened.

Answer (score 2):

Yes the Chinese government has blocked access to Google.com, Gmail, Google Maps, Google Docs, Google Analytics, Google Drive, and many other Google services as the Communist Party of China holds the 18th Party Congress, which started Thursday morning.

Google has confirmed the block with The Next Web, and a Google spokesperson offered the following statement: “We’ve checked and there’s nothing wrong on our end.”

On November 10th: Service has been “restored.”

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Google Analytics is blocked.

The only working Google thing in China seems to be translate.google.cn