# Google Tag Manager blocked in China..?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Our site uses Google Tag Manager and we have China users having issues - pointing to GTM as the culprit.

I know and read that major google services are blocked in China, but does this include www.googletagmanager.com?

[image]

Ive read from [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/37734/is-google-analytics-blocked-in-china) that Google Analytics is blocked, and read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23640645/what-is-the-difference-between-google-tag-manager-and-google-analytics) that GA is different from GTM.

Is there a possibility that GA is blocked, while GTM is allowed?
Or GTM is blocked, based on the screen shot above?

Is it possible to request from China user for a trace route maybe?

Need your insights please.

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure what the actual truth is. The vendor (Tealium) said that they are not blocked in China and for that reason my client purchased Tealium.

Answer (score 2):

According to [GreatFire](https://en.greatfire.org/https/www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js), Google Tag Manager is currently not blocked in China.

This doesn't mean that much though; the Chinese censors may have decided not to block GMT continuously, but only in intervals to make it seem Google is at fault.

Comment: yea, doesnt make sense at all, my testings are just recently and greatfire is telling that there were no blocks in the last 90 days.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's included.

Don't use GTM in China.

Other scripts depend on GTM to properly work. If GTM is blocked, you also block lot of traffic from using other non Google-scripts integrated in GTM.

You can continue using GA (and you need to adapt), but avoid GTM in China.

Answer (score 0):

yes and no, yes because the library script is still accessible, but slow, no because the entire UI is blocked in China.
http://www.chinaweboptimization.com/2018/03/google-analytics-gtm-blocked-china/